# Check if DEBUG in python Bottle

Tags: python, bottle

I'm using [Bottle 0.12](https://bottlepy.org/docs/0.12/),

how to use the `DEBUG` global to check if I'm running the development server — or another mean to check in the app if `app.run(debug=True)` is running?

What I want to achieve is to e.g. make some routes available only in debug

```
from bottle import DEBUG

@app.route('/debug')
def debug():
    if not DEBUG:
        abort(404)
    return template('debug.html')
```

I see a global `DEBUG` variable in `bottle` source code code which is always `False` when tested, even if dev server is running with `app.run(debug=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import bottle

@app.route('/debug')
def debug():
    if not bottle.DEBUG:
        abort(404)
    return template('debug.html')
```

Comment: Hello @kevic yes, it works, my sample code fails if I do `form bottle import DEBUG` which is counter-intuitive to me...

Comment: Hello @neurino, yes, it's true. Is it possible that the value was changed after the import? 
I think when you import the variable the value is false.

Comment: Hello @kevic, I tried to figure out what happens in the source code without luck. Nevertheless your code works, answer accepted :)

Comment: Thanks @neurino. I think you can also do a local import in the debug function.